# Proof of Lemma in "Harmonic maps and the self-duality equations" by Donaldson

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

I am referring to [this](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-55/1/127.extract) paper by S. K. Donaldson. I could not find a freely available version, hence I feel uncomfortable to copy & paste parts of his paper, and won't do so. Nevertheless, I will have to reference it.

I am trying to understand the proof of part a.) of his sole Lemma (p.129). I'm fine up to and including the very last equality concerning $\Gamma_{dH}$ at the bottom of p.129. What I do not see is how pulling back this term gives the equality of definitions.

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain this to me.

Thank you.